# Oracle database performance :- How to calculate read response time for a single block and for multiple blocks for oracle database 12 c?

Tags: oracle, performance, metrics

How to calculate read response time for a single block and for multiple blocks for oracle database 12c?
Is there a metric view present where we can see information pertaining to blocks?
like v$stat and v$sysmetric?
I looked around on different websites including oracle's but could not find much info except 'Average Synchronous Single-Block Read Latency' present in v$sysmetric  view of my database.
Are Average Synchronous Single-Block Read Latency and single block read response time same?

Comment: are you searching for something like `v$filestat`  this https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:978926765838 ?

Comment: That was a great help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use V$filestat , this view table containes the number of physical reads and writes happend on logical and block row  also you can check

```
select file#, phyrds,
phywrts
from v$filestat
```

you can do a select on v$datafile  to get the name of the data file

```
select * from v$datafile where file#=(file number get it from filestat)
```

from the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_1107.htm#REFRN30087)

> This view displays the number of physical reads and writes done and
>   the total number of single-block and multiblock I/Os done at file
>   level. As of Oracle Database 10g Release 2 (10.2), this view also
>   includes reads done by RMAN processes for backup operations.